# Executing function from a procedure but getting Conversion failed error (Varchar to Int)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-function

I have 1 procedure which calls function in loop.
I am using sql server 2008

Procedure

```
Alter PROCEDURE CalculateIndividualPoint
@WinningTeam varchar(50),
@MatchId varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN
Declare @LoopCounter INT = 1
Declare @Result INT
Declare @TotalCount INT

Select @TotalCount = COUNT(MatchId) from tblPlayerPoints Where MatchId = @MatchId

While @LoopCounter < @TotalCount
Begin
    Select @Result = dbo.PointsLoop(@MatchId,@WinningTeam,@LoopCounter)
    Update tblPlayerPoints
    Set CalcPoints = @Result 
    Where UserId = @LoopCounter
End
END

Function

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[PointsLoop]
(
@matchId varchar(50),
@WinningTeam varchar(50),
@LoopCounter int
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @pointer INT
Declare @MatchPoints1 INT
Declare @MatchPoints2 INT
Declare @FinalPoints Float
Declare @Xfactor varchar(50)

if @WinningTeam = 'Team1'
Begin
    Select @Xfactor = Team1Total from tblSchedule where MatchId = @matchId
    Select @Xfactor = CONVERT(Float,@Xfactor)
End
Else
Begin
    Select @Xfactor = Team2Total from tblSchedule Where MatchId = @matchId
    Select @Xfactor = CONVERT(Float,@Xfactor)
End

    Select @MatchPoints1 = Team1Points, @MatchPoints2 = Team2Points from tblPlayerPoints 
    where MatchId =@matchId and UserId = @LoopCounter
    Select @MatchPoints1 = CONVERT(float,@MatchPoints1)
    Select @MatchPoints2 = CONVERT(float,@MatchPoints2)
    if  @WinningTeam = 'Team1'
    Begin
        if @MatchPoints1 = 0 
        Begin
            Set @FinalPoints = - @MatchPoints2
        End
        Else
        Begin
            Set @FinalPoints = @MatchPoints1 * @Xfactor 
        End
    End 
    Else
    Begin 
        if @MatchPoints2 = 0 
        Begin
            Set @FinalPoints = - @MatchPoints1
        End
        Else
        Begin
            Set @FinalPoints = @MatchPoints2 * @Xfactor 
        End 
    End
Select @FinalPoints = CONVERT(int,@FinalPoints)
RETURN @FinalPoints

END
```

After Executing procedure i am getting following error. Team1Total and Team2Total are varchar datatype so i declared Xfactor as varchar(Where i am receiving 0.714286 value)  and then converting it to float still getting same error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0.714286' to data type int.

Comment: Did any of these answers help you with your problem? If yes please mark the helpful answer so that other users could benefit from it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the below statements you are trying to push calculated FLOAT value into INTEGER datatype variable called **@FinalPoints**

```
Select @FinalPoints = @MatchPoints1 * @Xfactor

Select @FinalPoints = @MatchPoints2 * @Xfactor
```

Comment: But in my code Team1Total value is not getting stored in Xfactor value. Also I tried changing everything to float till calculation part and at the end before return i changed it to int still i am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

In order to compute the result, SQL needs to convert all parts of the formula to the same data type. In this case, since the result is int, and the first variable in the formula is also int, `@Xfactor` is being implicitly converted to int, where it fails because the value of the variable is clearly not an integer.

Try this and you will get the same error:

```
DECLARE @Xfactor varchar(20) = '0.714286';
SELECT CONVERT(int, @Xfactor)
```

In your case I would suggest introducing a variable `@Xfactor_float` and use it in the formula.

In addition, I would recommend always casting explicitly all variables to the desired precision. For example, while SQL will by default convert datatypes to the one with the most precision, it may not be a desirable way. For example you may not desire to have everything being implicitly converted to float instead of decimal.

To address your comment - change your code to this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[PointsLoop]
(
@matchId varchar(50),
@WinningTeam varchar(50),
@LoopCounter int
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @pointer INT
Declare @MatchPoints1 INT
Declare @MatchPoints2 INT
Declare @FinalPoints Float
Declare @Xfactor varchar(50)
DECLARE @Xfactor_float float;

if @WinningTeam = 'Team1'
Begin
    Select @Xfactor = Team1Total from tblSchedule where MatchId = @matchId
    Select @Xfactor_float = CONVERT(Float,@Xfactor)
End
Else
Begin
    Select @Xfactor = Team2Total from tblSchedule Where MatchId = @matchId
    Select @Xfactor_float = CONVERT(Float,@Xfactor)
End

    Select @MatchPoints1 = Team1Points, @MatchPoints2 = Team2Points from tblPlayerPoints 
    where MatchId =@matchId and UserId = @LoopCounter
    Select @MatchPoints1 = CONVERT(float,@MatchPoints1)
    Select @MatchPoints2 = CONVERT(float,@MatchPoints2)
    if  @WinningTeam = 'Team1'
    Begin
        if @MatchPoints1 = 0 
        Begin
            Set @FinalPoints = - @MatchPoints2
        End
        Else
        Begin
            Set @FinalPoints = @MatchPoints1 * @Xfactor_float
        End
    End 
    Else
    Begin 
        if @MatchPoints2 = 0 
        Begin
            Set @FinalPoints = - @MatchPoints1
        End
        Else
        Begin
            Set @FinalPoints = @MatchPoints2 * @Xfactor_float 
        End 
    End
Select @FinalPoints = CONVERT(int,@FinalPoints)
RETURN @FinalPoints

END
```

Comment: I tried changing everything to float till calculation part and at the end before return i changed it to int still i am getting same error. (Code Updated)

Comment: I added a piece of code to illustrate my suggestion above. Varchars should never be user in math formulas. Convert them to an appropriate datatype and then do the math.